# Why can't Try Ubuntu connect to wifi (Broadcom driver enabled)

Tags: wireless, internet, broadcom, router, livedvd

Dell Vostro 2520
Dell Wireless 1704 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz)
[image: Broadcom network drivers:]
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Windows 10

Ubuntu booted from the hard disk (`sda5`), recognises the Broadcom hardware and driver, and connects to the wifi router and thence the Internet. Dual-booting from Windows 10 also uses the Broadcom-sourced driver and connects to the wifi network.

But booting from Try Ubuntu 22.04.1 on the Live DVD and switching to Broadcom driver does not recognise wifi router-modem so you cannot select it from the top-right menu and enter the wifi password. The router is simply not listed.

I've tried banging my head on the wall but that does not seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: You mention "*switching to broadcom driver*" but not how you did that; have you inserted the kernel module so it's available?  or installed in a manner that requires reboot (*which can be a problem with 'live' media!*).  Please be specific (are you asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop?  Ubuntu 22.04 Server? for one or both? etc)  You *graphic* shows windows modules; they likely won't be of much use when using a linux kernel (ie. use Linux kernel modules)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite the conundrum isn't it? You can't connect to the internet yet you can't enable the Broadcom driver unless you are connected to the Internet.

Set up you smart phone as a hotspot (a.k.a. as tethering). If possible, specify Cable Connection when setting up tethering.

You must have installed Ubuntu already on your laptop. With laptop switched off, join your smartphone and laptop with appropriate USB cable. Switch on your laptop and launch Ubuntu, you know, the one that won't connect to the internet.

Test whether the laptop is accessing the Internet via your phone by launching an Ubuntu app or by opening the terminal and pinging a server, e.g.

`$ ping www.adobe.com`

If the server returns test packets, type `Ctrl-c` to stop  `ping`.

1/ In Ubuntu, launch Software and Updates, and click the Alternate Drivers tab. Wait until the proprietary drivers are listed.
2/ Then click the radio button for the Broadcom driver.
3/ Click the Apply Changes button. Wait until the progress bar finishes.
4/ Exit Software and Updates.
5/ Disconnect your smartphone.

Now select your usual wifi router/modem and enter its password. Then try pinging a server again. If it returns test packets you are done!